# ASP.net convert SqlDataReader to tree

Tags: c#, asp.net, recursion, tree

Given the simple data structure:

```
ID    |    Category_Name    |    Parent_ID
```

Example:

```
1          Cars                    0
2          Boxes                   0
3          Lamborghinis            1
4          Camper Vans             1
5          Big Boxes               2
6          Small Boxes             2
7          Cereal Boxes            2
8          Broken Lambos           3
9          Yellow Ones             3
10         Rusty                   8
11         Milkshake Stained       8
12         Chocolate Flavour       11
13         Strawberry              11
14         Indiscernible Solution  11
```

Along with my code:

```
// Fetch current site setting
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID, catName, parentID FROM tblProductCats ORDER BY parentID ASC", cn))
{
    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (rdr.HasRows)
    {
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            // Fetch data
            int catID = int.Parse(rdr[0].ToString());
            string catName = rdr[1].ToString();
            int catParent = int.Parse(rdr[2].ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

I need to convert that returned data into a tree structure so I can go through it displaying the menu in a pretty way!

I've been stuck on this for a while any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say we have a class/struct Category such that

```
public class Category
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set; }

  private Category _Parent;
  public Category Parent {get { return _Parent; } 
   set {
     _Parent = value;
     _Parent.Children.Add(this);
   }
  }

  public List<Category> Children {get; private set; }

  public Category()
  {
    Children = new List<Category>();
  }
}
```

Now, if your query always order category's parent before it self then you can use below code

```
  var dict = new Dictionary<int, Category>();
  Category tree = null;
  while (rdr.Read())
    {
        // Fetch data
        int catID = int.Parse(rdr[0].ToString());
        string catName = rdr[1].ToString();
        int catParent = int.Parse(rdr[2].ToString());

        var category = new Category();
        category.Id = catID;
        category.Name = catName;
        dict[catID] = category;
        if (catParent > 0) {
           category.Parent = dict[catParent];
        }
        if (null == tree) 
        {
          tree = category;
        }
    }
```

So Tree variable should have your category tree.

Comment: That looks like an excellent answer, but I'm having trouble working out how to loop through the tree from the top (level 0) downwards?  I'm probably being thick but I'm not familiar with dictionary

Comment: never mind im thick!  i think I can work it out, thanks again :D

Comment: Missed that part completely. Edited answer to have Category.Children property. Note that implementation is simplistic and can be made better.

Comment: Pretty much figured it out, tree.Name accesses the first top level node, but how do you access the other top level nodes?

Comment: Didn't code for multiple top level nodes but you can easily do that by maintaining a list of roots. if catParent = 0 then add the category to list of roots.

Comment: thank you, I've done it and it works great, is it ok if I edit your answer with my updated code incase anyone else wants to use it in the future?

Comment: Sure, go ahead and edit it. If you can't edit then you can always add as new answer.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Display Hierarchical Data with TreeView in ASP.NET](http://aspalliance.com/articleViewer.aspx?aId=732&pId=-1).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like an optimal solution, but maybe you can find some inspiration in this [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Building_Trees.aspx).